# Counting the number of entries in a dataframe that satisfies multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with 9 columns, two of which are gender and smoker status. Every row in the dataframe is a person, and each column is their entry on a particular trait.
I want to count the number of entries that satisfy the condition of being both a smoker and is male.
I have tried using a sum function:

```
maleSmoke = sum(1 for i in data['gender'] if i is 'm' and i in data['smoker'] if i is 1 )
```

but this always returns 0. This method works when I only check one criteria however and I can't figure how to expand it to a second.
I also tried writing a function that counted its way through every entry into the dataframe but this also returns 0 for all entries.

```
def countSmokeGender(df):
    maleSmoke = 0
    femaleSmoke = 0
    maleNoSmoke = 0
    femaleNoSmoke = 0
    
    for i in range(20000):
        if df['gender'][i] is 'm' and df['smoker'][i] is 1:
            maleSmoke = maleSmoke + 1
        if df['gender'][i] is 'f' and df['smoker'][i] is 1:
            femaleSmoke = femaleSmoke + 1
        if df['gender'][i] is 'm' and df['smoker'][i] is 0:
            maleNoSmoke = maleNoSmoke + 1
        if df['gender'][i] is 'f' and df['smoker'][i] is 0:
            femaleNoSmoke = femaleNoSmoke + 1
    
    return maleSmoke, femaleSmoke, maleNoSmoke, femaleNoSmoke
```

I've tried pulling out the data sets as numpy arrays and counting those but that wasn't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `pandas`?

Assuming you are, you can simply do this:

```py
# How many male smokers
len(df[(df['gender']=='m') & (df['smoker']==1)])
# How many female smokers
len(df[(df['gender']=='f') & (df['smoker']==1)])
# How many male non-smokers
len(df[(df['gender']=='m') & (df['smoker']==0)])
# How many female non-smokers
len(df[(df['gender']=='f') & (df['smoker']==0)])
```

Or, you can use `groupby`:

```py
df.groupby(['gender'])['smoker'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, which is great for data exploration: [`.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot-table)

With a DataFrame like this

```
    id gender  smoker  other_trait
0    0      m       0            0
1    1      f       1            1
2    2      m       1            0
3    3      m       1            1
4    4      f       1            0
..  ..    ...     ...          ...
95  95      f       0            0
96  96      f       1            1
97  97      f       0            1
98  98      m       0            0
99  99      f       1            0
```

you could do

```
result = df.pivot_table(
    index="smoker", columns="gender", values="id", aggfunc="count"
)
```

to get a result like

```
gender   f   m
smoker        
0       32  16
1       27  25
```

If you want to display the partial counts you can add the `margins=True` option and get

```
gender   f   m  All
smoker             
0       32  16   48
1       27  25   52
All     59  41  100
```

If you don't have a column to count over (you can't use `smoker` and `gender` because they are used for the labels) you could add a dummy column:

```
result = df.assign(dummy=1).pivot_table(
    index="smoker", columns="gender", values="dummy", aggfunc="count",
    margins=True
)
```